# Let $H$ be an infinite hyperbolic group. Can $H \rtimes \mathbb Z$ ever be hyperbolic?

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, semidirect-product

It is well known that hyperbolic groups cannot contain a copy of $\mathbb Z^2$. It follows that if $H$ is infinite and hyperbolic, then $G = H \times \mathbb Z$ cannot be hyperbolic, as $H$ will contain some non-torsion element which will then commute with the generator of $\mathbb Z$.

I'm curious as to what happens if we restrict this condition slightly, in particular, we have the following:

> Let $H$ be an infinite hyperbolic group. Can $H \rtimes_\phi \mathbb Z$ ever be hyperbolic for any choice of $\phi$?

My instinct is that the geometry of the situation prohibits this, but I cannot quite see how to show it. Any help or examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Your instinct is almost right. The correct result is that if $H$ and $H\rtimes Z$ are hyperbolic, then $H$ is (virtually) a free product of free groups and surface groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are early examples arising in Thurston's work during the age of hyperbolic manifolds, a little before the era of hyperbolic groups: if $H = \pi_1(S)$ where $S$ is a closed, oriented surface of genus $g \ge 2$ (and so $H$ is hyperbolic), and if $\phi \in \text{Aut}(H)$ is induced by a pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism of $S$, then $H \rtimes_\phi \mathbb Z$ is the fundamental group of closed hyperbolic 3-manifold (and so $H \rtimes_\phi \mathbb Z$ is a hyperbolic group).

The actual statement of the examples above *expressed in the language of hyperbolic groups* was given first, as an application of Thurston's earlier work, in a paper of Bestvina and Feighn. In that same paper they produced further examples: for any free group $H$ of finite rank $\ge 2$ and for any $\phi \in \text{Aut}(H)$, if there does not exist a proper, nontrivial free factor $F < H$ and $n \ge 1$ such that $\phi^n(F)$ is conjugate to $F$, and if there does not exist an infinite cyclic subgroup $C < H$ and $n \ge 1$ such that $\phi^n(C)$ is conjugate to $C$, then $H \rtimes_\phi \mathbb Z$ is a hyperbolic group.